# How to make Cyrillic datasets recognizable?

Tags: r, view, dataset, transform, cyrillic

One dataset from Russian Election studies is written in Cyrillic letters, but R can not recognize Cyrillic letters and shows instead some weird symbols, if I use `view(rusdata)` and I would like to convert this dataset in a way, that the Cyrillic letters are recognized by R.

Here is what I already tried and what didn't help me:

```
rusdata <-read.spss("RES 2007-2008.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE)

Sys.setlocale(locale = "Russian")
view(rusdata)
Sys.setlocale(,"ru_RU")
view(rusdata)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")
encoding = "utf-8"
view(rusdata)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU.UTF-8")
view(rusdata)
```

I would really welcome your help!

Comment: Encoding problems are nasty . Try  `rvest::guess_encoding` on one of the columns

Comment: I used R to work with Russian text before and it is generally supported. However, you sometimes have trouble *displaying* the symbols. This is especially true if you use an older version of RStudio. The underlying data is often fine though. So try writing your data to disk and check if it is really damaged after going through R or if its fine, in which case you can work with the data and just need a different way to display it. More often than not it's actually fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try your luck with a different package such as `haven::read_sav`. Alternatively, I would use `stringi::stri_enc_detect` to detect encoding first. I assume you can copy a part of the text from spss. Here is an example:

```
a <- "Статья 1;Все люди рождаются"
stringi::stri_enc_detect(a)
```

Then I would use the encoding returned by `stri_enc_detect`:

```
rusdata <-read.spss("RES 2007-2008.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE, reencode = "encoding goes here")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I try it out!

Comment: unfortunately didn't help with .csv dataframe

Comment: @Angelika If you provide a reproducible example, I can try to have a look. Without being able to reproduce the issue, it is hard to help, unfortunately.